# How can I change this code to toggle when the screen reaches 500px in width?

Tags: jquery, screen

```
<script>
try {
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#video1').VideoPlayer({
            theme: '-vid-skin'              
        });

        $("a.video-link, #video-overlay-shadow").bind("click", function() {
            $("#video-overlay-shadow, #ms-video-overlay").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
            if($(".Vid-play-button").hasClass("Vid-paused-button")) $(".Vid-play-button").trigger("click");
        });
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(lel);
}

</script>
```

How can I modify this piece of code so that when the screen width reaches 500px it triggers?

Comment: Sorry should have also said that I still want to trigger by clicking a.video-link and #video-overlay-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `resize` event. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

For example:

```
$(window).resize(
    function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
);
```

Of course, you should consider the likely situations in which after the initial trigger the window is made even wider or narrower than 500px.

---

If you need this to be triggered just once when the window is made wider than 500px, you need to check for that somehow. For example, you can use the `data` method to indicate the window has already went over 500px:

```
$(window).resize(
    function() {
         // Window just went over 500 for the first time
        if ($(window).width() >= 500 && !$(window).data('already_over_500')) {
            $(window).data('already_over_500'); // Set a flag for the first time
            // Do something...

         // Window just went below 500
        } else if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            $(window).data('already_over_500',''); // Unset the flag
            // Do something else...
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Ya thinking about that, I want it to trigger the pause function when getting to 500px and then restart it when it gets larger.

Comment: So I used your code and modded it a bit so that it looks like this: `$(window).resize(
    function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
          $("#ms-video-overlay-shadow, #ms-video-overlay").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    if($(".msVid-play-button").hasClass("msVid-paused-button")) $(".msVid-play-button").trigger("click");  
        }
    }
);` But now it triggers all the time once you got below 500px.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking to do, but what you're describing would be trigger every time the window is resized and stays over 500px. For example, say the first it time it goes straight to 600 and then back to 550, it would be triggered twice. You need to check somehow for the initial trigger. I will edit the answer with an example.

Comment: I have solved it, I'll put up the code later on sorry. Its Pretty much the same to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  if($(window).width() >= 500){
    // your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Provide some description also. So, other user also can understand how your code works.